# Creating Dynamic UL LI

Tags: c#, dynamic, html-lists, stringbuilder

Im trying to create a dynamic Ul Li based on data recieved from the Database

Basically the columns i recieve from the DB are as follows
1.CategoryID
2.ParentCategoryID
3.Href
4.Name.

Now i use the following loop to create my UL.

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (rdr["ParentCategoryID"].ToString() == "")
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl newLI = 
            new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("li");

        newLI.Attributes.Add("class", "Item-"+(i+1));
        newLI.ID = "id" + i;
        newLI.InnerHtml = "<a href=" + '"' + 
                             rdr["Href"].ToString() + "/default.aspx" + 
                            '"' +'>' + 
                            "<span>" + rdr["Name"]+"</span>" + "</a>";
        newUL.Controls.Add(newLI);
        i++;
    }
}
```

In this case I only create the top level of the UL... But this is a multilevel UL

Assuming my inout is as follows

> `CategoryID ParentCategoryID Href   Name`
>
> `1             NULL          /a-d   A-C`
>
> `2              1            /a      A`
>
> `3              1            /b      B`
>
> `4              1            /c      C`
>
> `5             NULL          /d-e    D-E`
>
> `6              5            /d      D`
>
> `7              5            /e      E`
>
> `8             NULL          /f-g    F-G`
>
> `9              8            /f      F`
>
> `10             8            /g      G`

Currently my code works until the point whre i get

- A-C
- D-E
- F-G

How do i improve this so i get the sub categories to list under the parent categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you order the items by `ParentCategoryID`, you can perform a second pass to add all the elements with a non-NULL parent category.

Simply add the new items to the `Controls` property of the parent.

Usually I use a `Dictionary<Key, Value>` to keep track of the existing elements and be able to quickly access them by ID.

Last, if you order the whole data by `ParentCategoryID` with `NULL` first, then by `CategoryID`, you should be able to do it in just one `while` loop.

Comment: How do i do the second pass?

Comment: Store the data read from the reader in a list, and run through the list a second time. If you read my last statement, you should be able to do it in one loop.

Comment: Yeah. I am doing that . Thanks. FInally i got my code working